# How to do two and more function in combineReducers - Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to integrate several functions into one
how do I do it ?

```
export default combineReducers({
  vacations: vacationsReducer,
  User:  {User_followcounter, User_LOG_IN} 
});
```

It doesn't work, for example

```
User:  {User_followcounter, User_LOG_IN} 

import { FOLLOW, UNFOLLOW, LOG_IN, LOG_OUT, } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    USER_FOLLOW: false,
    IS_LOG_IN: false,
}


export const User_followcounter = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FOLLOW:
            return { FOLLOW: state.FOLLOW = true };

        case UNFOLLOW:
            return { FOLLOW: state.FOLLOW = false };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const User_LOG_IN = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOG_IN:
            return { IS_LOG_IN: state.FOLLOW = true };

        case LOG_OUT:
            return { IS_LOG_IN: state.FOLLOW = false };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default { User_followcounter, User_LOG_IN }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

Reducers.js

```
import { FOLLOW, UNFOLLOW, LOG_IN, LOG_OUT, } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    USER_FOLLOW: false,
    IS_LOG_IN: false,
}


export const User_followcounter = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FOLLOW:
            return { FOLLOW: state.FOLLOW = true };

        case UNFOLLOW:
            return { FOLLOW: state.FOLLOW = false };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export const User_LOG_IN = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOG_IN:
            return { IS_LOG_IN: state.FOLLOW = true };

        case LOG_OUT:
            return { IS_LOG_IN: state.FOLLOW = false };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

combineReducer.js

```
import { User_followcounter, User_LOG_IN } from './Reducers';

export default combineReducers({
  vacations: vacationsReducer,
  User_followcounter,
  User_LOG_IN
});
```

When you are already doing `export const User_followcounter` then why you need to combine into one object using `export default { User_followcounter, User_LOG_IN }`.
Look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for more information

Hope that helps!!!